# Angular Highcharts redraw

Tags: javascript, angularjs, highcharts

How can i trigger a redraw in the angular highcharts directive? The problem is i have contained my chart in a tab and it initializes badly. Like this : http://puu.sh/lVg8s/6d9e9f2083.png

If i resize the window it fixes itself for the selected tab instance, but i need to somehow do that as it loads up.

```
Application.controller('SalesReportsHistoryController', ['ServerActions', '$scope', 'initData', function( ServerActions, $scope, initData ){

    var history = this;

    history.initData = initData.data;

    $scope.$on('$viewContentLoaded', function () {
        $(window).resize(function () {
            console.log('resized!');
        });

        $(window).resize();
    });

... etc more code
```

This is what i tried, but no dice. The resize event fires, and if i fire it in the console it works as i expect, but not on load.

Comment: Would it be better to fix the problem, if possible, instead of forcing chart's resize/redraw? In chart's callback or [load event](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#chart.events.load) you should be able to set internal option `chart.isDirtyBox` to `true` (if needed) and call `chart.`[redraw](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Chart.redraw). [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ah6xbzw5/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose that you have full control over your data and know precisely when it's available or not. If the answer is yes, you can add an *ng-if* directive on the highcharts directive that triggers the repaint.

```
<div ng-if="showChart">
    <highchart></highchart>
</div>
```

Then in your controller then you can set *$scope.showChart* to either true or false depending on the availability of the chart's data. If that does not work, you can always set a timeout on *$scope.showChart* so it will be true only after whole DOM has been rendered.

Comment: So the chart is redrawn each time i hide/show the container? Because your method didn't fully work until i intialized my containers as hidden

Comment: In a short answer, yes. The chart is redrawn each time the container is re-added to the DOM (manipulation of the container triggers the repaint automatically). This is actually not so bad because you may add a spinner or loading icon in the future and it would be pretty easy to hook it in.